# association is not connected (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display `%h4 #{message.user_id.name}` with association of message model & user model

I'm getting an error:

```
Showing /Users/ryousuke/projects/chat-space/app/views/messages/_message.html.haml
undefined method `name' for 3707:Fixnum
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/messages/index.html.haml
```

I've tried...

- to check the association:

  ```
  class Message < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :group
  end

  class User < ApplicationRecord
  　has_many :messages
    has_many :group_users
    has_many :groups, through: :group_users
  end
  ```
- to check foreign_key:

  ```
  create_table "messages", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",               null: false
  t.text     "content",    `enter code here`limit: 65535, null: false
  t.string   "image"
  t.integer  "user_id",                  null: false
  t.integer  "group_id",                 null: false
  t.index ["group_id"], name: "fk_rails_841b0ae6ac", using: :btree
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "fk_rails_273a25a7a6", using: :btree
  ```
- to check data existence usertable id:3707

Comment: Isn't the information you provide self-explanatory? I am no expert on Ruby but you show that class 'User', doesn't have a property or method 'name'... Seem like you are skipping a step?

Comment: This has been solved! Thank you. It was such a easy mistake.

Answer (score 3):

`user_id` returns the ID - a number. What you want is just `user`, which will return the actual user object.

```
%h4 #{message.user.name}
```

Comment: thank you so much. I totally misunderstood. It was easy mistake.
This has been solved!

Comment: @RyosukeKuwabara You're welcome! Be sure to accept the answer so that this question is complete.